# Block Level Atomic Write

Tags: c++, c, cuda, gpu, gpgpu

is it possible to do an atomic write on the block level?
as an example consider the following:

```
__global__ kernel (int atomic)
{
    atomic+=blockid.x; //should be atomic for each block
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind, that if you set a tag [C] or [C++], people who have no knowledge of CUDA are going to read your question. As a result they may be confused about the nature of your problem and/or terminology that you are using (e.g. what is a block? what is `__global__`?). Either don't put that tag, or state explicitly that it is a CUDA problem.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

While unclear what you mean with block/block level, it sounds like you just need an atomic add.
Those are found in the kernel in `#include <asm/atomic.h>` your code would be

```
__global__ kernel (int atomic)
{
    atomic_add(blockid.x,&atomic);
}
```

`atomic` would have to be of type `atomic_t` and blockid.x an int.

Comment: and if i add #include <asm/atomic.h> i get  fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'asm/atomic.h': No such file or directory

Comment: ok got it. i should add sm_11 and its atomicAdd and not atomic_add. thank you.

Comment: What you say is actually not a solution for CUDA (not clear in the question - check the tags)

Comment: @randy: You accepted a completely incorrect answer.  Please accept pQB's answer instead, as it is correct for CUDA, whereas Lyke didn't read the question correctly.

Comment: @harrism: Well, 5 years later, it seems randy has not returned to this site and we're stuck with the wrong answer. I'll downvote it at least, and I've flagged it as "not an answer".

Comment: My "not an answer" flag was rejected by the moderator for some reason. I changed to "moderator attention needed".

Answer (score 3):

You can do some atomic operations in CUDA. See Apendix B.11 Atomic Functions in the CUDA Programming Guide. i.e.:

```
__global__ void kernel (int *result)
{
    atomicAdd(result, blockIdx.x); // 
}
```

You can also exchange the value of a variable

```
__global__ void kernel (int *result)
{
    atomicExch(result, blockIdx.x); // 
}
```

Both examples operates in Global Memory.

> Atomic functions operating on shared memory and atomic functions operating on 64-bit words are only available for devices of compute capability 1.2 and above.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform atomic operations on shared memory, but not the way you tried to do so in your code snippet: Your kernel's `int` parameter is a thread-specific variable; even though all threads get the same value you gave at launch, they don't store it in shared memory - and it's meaningless to operate on it atomically.

If you had passed, say, an `int *` to some buffer - that would be a buffer in global memory. You can perform device-wide-atomic operations on data in global memory, as described in @pQB's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6614835/1593077). But you asked about block-level atomic operations... that does not mean much for global data. Still, if one of your threads writes to some global address, it can all `__threadfence_block()` to stall until the effect of this write is visible to all other threads in the block.

Properly block-level atomics are also supported in CUDA, but - on shared memory. Read about how to use shared memory in [this Parallel4All blog entry](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/using-shared-memory-cuda-cc/) or in the relevant [section](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#shared-memory) the [CUDA Programming Guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html).

If you have some `__shared__ int x`, you can indeed perform a block-level atomic operation on it, with the same syntax as for global atomics: `atomicAdd(&x, 7)` will atomically add 123 to the value of x. But - remember all threads in the block will do the same, and you certainly don't want to try up to 1024 atomic writes at a time. Typically you would have something like

```
__shared__ some_buffer[NumFoosPerBar];

// ...

if (check_condition()) { 
     int foo_index = get_thread_foo_index_for(threadIdx.x);
     atomicAdd(&some_buffer[foo_index], 7);
}
```

where possibly more than one thread writes to the same location, but not necessarily. When you *do* expect multiple writes - don't use atomics, but rather perform some kind of reduction on the values to be written.